# Select in Select, o JOIN, para unir tablas. ¿Cuál es más eficaz?

Tags: mysql

tengo una duda sobre la eficacia de un par de consultas.
y quería saber la diferencia entre ellas.
las consultas obtienen los mismos datos, dado que se usan con un WHERE.

```
SELECT  tr.dato1,
  (SELECT
     p.nombre
   FROM prestador p
   WHERE (p.id_prestador = tr.id_prestador)) AS descripcion_prestador
FROM ticket_reserva tr
```

.

```
SELECT tr.dato1,
       p.descripcion_prestador
FROM ticket_reserva tr
JOIN prestador p ON tr.id_prestador = p.id_prestador
```

Comment: Hay consenso en que `JOIN` es más eficaz que una sub-consulta. Ver por ejemplo el MR: [*`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` puede ser más rápida que una subconsulta equivalente porque el servidor podría optimizarla mejor, un hecho que no es específico solo de MySQL Server.*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html).

Comment: Chequea que dice el explain plan ;)

Comment: Cuidado que las dos consultas no son exactamente iguales, la segunda es un `inner`  la primera es equivalente a un `left`, y coincido con los comentarios anteriores.

Comment: Eficaz no es lo mismo que eficiente. Tomando la definición de la RAE: "Eficacia:  Capacidad de lograr el efecto que se desea o se espera." para responder a tu pregunta, diría que ambas son igualmente eficaces, pues ambas logran el resultado que esperas. Ahora, probablemente no son igual de eficientes y quizás lo que quieras saber es cuál es más eficiente. En ese caso, solo se puede saber comparando los planes de ejecución en un motor particular y una base de datos particular. A primera vista, muchos dirán que el JOIN, probablemente ambas sean igual de eficientes, por la simpleza de la consulta

Comment: SQL es una lengua declarativa. En SQL decimos que data queremos ver, no como el DBMS tiene que lograrlo. Es posible, que las dos consultas resultan en el mismo plan. Con un optimizador perfecto, sería así. Es buen hábito escribir las consultas lo más simple posible. Sólo si una consulta sale muy lento (porque el optimizador tiene dificultades), la reescribiría.